# Meteor: How do you populate a field from one collection into another collection with _id field?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

In mongo I have a document that stores pending userId's in a collaborators object array and looks like this:

```
researchThread {
  _id: 4374583575745756
    pending: {
      collaborators: [
      {
        userId: '13745845754745753'
      },
      {
        userId: '23755845854745731' 
      },
      {
        userId: '33755845653741736'
      }]

  }
}
```

The userId is the _id field for the user from the users collection. Each user also has a name and an email field.

How can I populate the name and email fields from the user collection, into this document for each user in the researchThread.pending.collaborators object array? And also, will the populated data be reactive when used in the templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop through each collaborator, find the relevant user document by searching the users collection for the id, and update the researchThread document with that information.

The data will be reactive if the researchThread collection is a Meteor.Collection which you're drawing from in your templates.

However, why do you want to copy the user data? Why not just have Meteor query the users collection based on the researchThread userId when you need the data in the template?

Comment: So just do a database query on the client to the users collection and use the template helpers to place the users name and email in template? Any security issues with this?

Comment: Pretty much. Security is in a different layer. You should read about it in the Meteor docs to get an idea of how to handle it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this aspect of Meteor, but this seems inefficient. Would there be any benefit to grouping the _ids into a single users.find() query, then looping through the result, rather than potentially sending a new request for each collaborators item?

Comment: yes there would be.  and the question he asks at the end really hits the nail on the head, really what you should do is pull out the collaborators into a straight array (inside your publication or helper method depending on your setup and what you're after), probably using groupBy or an underscores method and then get them from your users collection (either on the client side, or on both again depending on your setup) using the $in operator to pass in the array.